# Start off UIPickerView With Blank Row

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview

My app pulls data from a server to get a list of current groups available to choose from.  It then adds a row to the top of this called "Create New Group".  This works great, but it starts off already selecting this row, so I have to navigate away from it, and then back again to select it and activate the keyboard.  How can I add one more option to get it to start with a blank row?  I have tried simply doing + 2 in the rows instead of + 1, and sorting everything down, but it simply doesn't work.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [pickerArray count] + 1;
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (row == 0)
    {
        [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField resignFirstResponder];
        self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView = nil;
        [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    else {

    [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setText:self.theGroup];
    }
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *groupName  = @"Create New Group";
    if (row != 0)
    {
        PFObject *object = pickerArray[row - 1]; // -1 to handle the array index
        self.theGroup    = object[@"GroupName"];
        groupName        = object[@"GroupName"];
    }
    return groupName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the down vote with no explanation as to why, or no attempt to help out.  Valid question, guys.

Comment: You are basically keeping one additional row for creating a new group and when you created the new group another additional row is created for that option. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Add empty string @" " or empty string with special html characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach adjusts your array by two, allowing for the blank space you requested. I also introduced switch statements to make it a bit easier to understand what is happening. Comments were added in code to highlight changes relevant to your request.

```
#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [pickerArray count] + 2; // This offsets your blank line & "Create new group" option
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch (row) {
            // Ignore 0 here since you don't want to handle the blank space
            case 1:
            [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField resignFirstResponder];
            self.theView.signUpView.additionalField.inputView = nil;
            [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        default:
            [self.theView.signUpView.additionalField setText:self.theGroup];
    }
}
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
            case 0:
            return @"";
            case 1:
            return @"Create New Group";
        default:
            PFObject *object = pickerArray[row - 2];
            self.theGroup    = object[@"GroupName"];
            return self.theGroup;
    }
}
```

I included the image below to show what this looks like when using some generic data.

[image]

Comment: I get an error on the titleForRow method, on the PFObject *object line stating it is expecting an expression, but can't figure out what the issue is (little sleep)

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need set numberOfRows +2.
2. Then titleForRow:0 return @"", titleForRow:1 return @"Create New Group"
3. Then you need select 0'th rows (programmatically if not autoselected)
4. And Then need check 0'th, 1'th and next values in didSelectRow.

Other idea:

Add to picker InputAccessoryView with button. And add action on this button, and remove logic in didSelect.